# Why does alphago only go to 19 numbers and 19 alphabet letter and not 26 numbers and 26 alphabet letters? Alphago max version?

Tags: combinatorial-games, data-visualization, bag-of-words, bag-of-features, visual-place-recognition

I was just looking at alpha go videos on youtube that google deep mind sent me and was wondering on the versioning board and it reminded me of a more advanced version of chess game on windows operating system and was just wondering where the game downloadable version of alphago is and if it's safe to play from a maths and comprehension perspective for various ages?

Also why does the english language alphabet only go to 26 letters and not more maths numbers and more "letters?"/symbols?

Whys there no alphago mini version with like 9 numbers side and 9 side letters like sudoku?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-_Cu6Hwp5U&list=TLPQMzAwOTIwMjNYMDhiHAClYA&index=219&ab_channel=GoogleDeepMind

https://www.deepmind.com/research/highlighted-research/alphago

Comment: is this a joke?...

Comment: @Alberto Safer to assume good faith intentions here, but difficulty in expressing the question.

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. We cannot answer definitively why the developers of AlphaGo have not publsihed versions that already allow for larger or smaller boards. It's probably just a time/attention constraint, and there is no benefit to them to cover yet more variations of Go. They have published papers on how it works though, so you can read them, and if you become confident and have time you could make your own. A 9x9 board player should be something a hobbyist could target for a project lasting a few months to a few years